# Resize shape with text in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010

I pasted a drawing from PowerPoint to Word that has shapes with text. The drawing is much too large; but when I make it smaller, the text remains the same size and ruins the layout. Is there a way of reducing a shape along with the text it contains?

Comment: yes, check the re-size text with box option

Comment: @Buscar웃, sounds promising. Where would I find this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerPoint you could do following, that would allow you to auto scale the text with object size.

[image]

If you copy objects from PowerPoint to Word, there is no such option in Word.

In that case just paste the object as Picture, using the paste special command.

Now when you re-size the picture the text will re-size automatically.

Comment: I would have preferred an actual "resize text with box" option, but it looks like this is the best it can do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manually edit the text size for a better fit after re-sizing the shape.

Comment: Ended up doing just that.